# Android: how to pass object between activities with object contains other objects

Tags: android, android-activity, serializable

I'm begginer in Android and i try to pass object between activities with object contains other objects but errors appear.

A solution?

I try to pass object with serializable :

```
        lALL.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v,
                    int position, long arg3) {
                System.out.println(position);
                Locataire l = new Locataire(getResources());
                l.setNom("test");
                l.setPrenom("test");
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Etat_lieux.class);
                intent.putExtra("EDL", l);
                startActivity(intent);      
            }


        });
```

And

```
public class Locataire implements Serializable{

private String ref;
private String civilite;
private String nom;
private String prenom;
private Contact contact = new Contact();
private Adresse adresse = new Adresse();
private String DG;
private boolean IsGarantPresent;
private boolean IsColocation;

private Resources res;

public Locataire(Resources res)
{
    this.res = res;
}
```

Contact,Adresse

public class Contact implements Serializable{

```
protected String tel;
protected String mobile;
protected String fax;
protected String email;
protected String www;
```

And ressource is Context getResources() of first activity

Comment: Paste stacktrace so we can get better view of the error

Comment: What about `Contact`,`Adresse`,`Resources` etc ? Are they `Serializable`?

Comment: error is parcelable encountered ioexception writing serializable object resource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass data between activities in your own app you should use `startActivity`, `startActivityForResult` and `onActivityResult`. You create a Bundle object and encapsulate your data in it with `putExtra`. Then you retrieve this object in your `onCreate` method.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

Otherwise, if you want to pass data between activities in your app and activities in another app you should use explicit or implicit intents.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass object in extras... you have to make the object implements serializable..and make all it sub-objects implement serializalbe.. 
then use bundle.putSerializable(OBJECT)..